# Change Wordpress Tag Tooltip

Tags: wordpress, tags

How to change Tag tooltip as Tag Description?

I tried and my code is mentioned below.

```
function title_text( $description ) {
    return sprintf( _n('%s topic', '%s', $description), $description );
}

wp_tag_cloud( array( 'topic_count_text_callback' => 'title_text') );
```

This is not working. Can any one please check this code and find me a correct solution?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is the callback not being registered? Or is it being called but not returning the right result?

Comment: It is not returning right result. Output should be => Tooltip should display Tag Description. But, it is displaying 1 topic or 2 topic